# Onsen UI myNavigator.pushPage() function not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I have a login page as a template within my index.html. I want to redirect the user from login.html to main.html in the same page. Its coming back with error :

> Cannot call method pushPage of undefined

```
<ons-template id="login.html" style="background:#000; opacity:0.3">

        <ons-page ng-controller="RegisterController">

            <ons-row style="padding-top:5em;">
                <ons-col>
                      <div class="formarea">

                        <div class="form-row">
                          <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar width-full" placeholder="Email" id= "email" ng-model="email">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                          <input type="password" class="text-input--underbar width-full" id="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model = "password" value="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="lucent">
                          <p class="note">Password - 6 characters or more</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="vspc form-row">
                          <ons-button modifier="large" style="color:#777" ng-click="loginUser();">Login</ons-button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="vspc form-row">
                          <ons-button modifier="large" style="color:#777">Signup</ons-button>
                        </div>                  
                      </div>
              </ons-col>
            </ons-row>

        </ons-page> 

</ons-template>

<ons-template id="main.html">
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
        <ons-page >
            <ons-tabbar position="top" var="tabbar">
              <ons-tabbar-item  style="margin-top:20px;border-right:1px solid #f5f5f5" icon="ion-navicon greyicon2" onclick="menu.toggleMenu()"></ons-tabbar-item>
              <ons-tabbar-item page="dashboard.html"  icon="ion-ios-pulse-strong" active="true"  class="tab-bar__button tab-bar--top-border__button"></ons-tabbar-item>
              <ons-tabbar-item page="history.html"  icon="ion-stats-bars greyicon2"></ons-tabbar-item>
              <ons-tabbar-item page="recommend.html"  icon="ion-star greyicon2"></ons-tabbar-item>
              <ons-tabbar-item page="capture.html"  icon="ion-pinpoint greyicon2"></ons-tabbar-item> 
            </ons-tabbar>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
</ons-template>
```

**Controller**

```
    ons.ready(function() {
      $scope.navigatorx = $window.myNavigator
    }); 

$scope.navigatorx.pushPage('main.html');
```

Also have ons-sliding menu

```
<ons-sliding-menu var="menu" main-page="main.html" menu-page="menux.html" max-slide-distance="85%" type="reveal" side="left" >
</ons-sliding-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigator docs [here](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html).
Right now you don't have any main page or component, only templates. Remove `<ons-template id="main.html">` wrapper and let `<ons-navigator var="myNavigator">` be the main element.

Also, `var="myNavigator"` is the name of the navigator's variable that will be available both in `window.myNavigator` and `$scope.myNavigator`.

Comment: If I remove main.html the ons-menu stops working - please see above

Answer (score 0):

If I remove "main.html" then my `<ons-sliding>` stops working.

```
 <ons-sliding-menu var="menu" main-page="main.html" menu-page="menux.html" max-slide-distance="85%" type="reveal" side="left" >
</ons-sliding-menu>
```